# How to add an extra parameter to a Django object when creating it?

Tags: django

I have a Django model that has many parameters, amongst which is one called 'system' which is a reference to an object of type 'System'.

```
class Format(models.Model):
   system = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   petition_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
   resolution_date = models.DateField(null=True, default=None)
   ... other fields ...
```

The system may be null, but I'd want this field to be the same as the user that creates the Format object.
My user object is like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   current_system = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None)
   department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None)
```

I have a form which successfully creates the Format objects. However, I'd like to know a way to do something like this in my CreateView:

```
class FormatCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """
           -----------------------Vista de crear nuevos articulos--------------------------
    """
    template_name = 'format_form.html'
    model = Format
    success_url = reverse_lazy("formats:formats")
    form_class = FormatUpdateForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = FormatUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
            format = self.object  # I'm pretty sure this is wrong and doesn't get the Format object that was just created
            format.system = user.current_system
            format.save(update_fields=['system'])
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('formats:formats'))
```

This, however, doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Also, I forgot to mention, when doing that, the Format object is no longer being created after completing and sending the form.

Comment: Try with `format = form.instance`

Comment: I forgot to mention the Format object is also not being created when I override the post method like that, but I don't know how overriding it like that makes it not create the object anymore.

Comment: You can use `new_obj = form.save(commit=False)` then modify the new object and save it using `new_obj.save()`